# Which account is office using?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-account

I have a windows 10 laptop of my own at home. With this laptop I use a personal (gmail) email address for Microsoft account login with OneDrive and VS2015. I login to the Office products (i.e. word, excel, etc) using my Office365 work email login to use the work license solely for those products.

However, when I open word I see in the top right hand corner my name and my *personal* email address. If I click switch account the panel that opens shows just one account which lists my name and *both* email addresses! (First my name, then my personal email address, then my work email address).

Which login are the office products actually using??

Note: My personal email address login *does* have access to an office 365 license due to being added to a relatives subscription - however this addition was only agreed for the use of their additional OneDrive space and I do not want to take up one of their additional office subscriptions, this is the main reason I want to confirm which account is actually in use.

**EDIT**

The below image shows the switch account panel with the initial account with both email addresses and the now newly added account (marked current account in the image) with just the work email which appears after adding after Ramhound's comment.

[image: image of accounts]

Comment: "Which login are the office products actually using??" - Based on your "note", Office is using your personal account.  You can switch which account is being used from within office.

Comment: OK, I used the "Add Account option from the mentioned panel. Am still unsure why/how the other account lists _both_ email addresses??

Comment: I don't have a Office 2016/365 installation in front of me.  What do you mean exactly?

Comment: added image to question to demonstrate

Comment: I believe "Why/how the other account lists both email addresses?" is a different question and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the current account shown within an Office application. Launch e.g. Word and you see the account information in the top right corner. You can disconnect that account or add nother from the `File` `->` `Account` menu. Tested this with Office 2016 on Windows 10.

**Edit:** Ramhound already gave you an answer specific to your case, and it seems that you already knew where to look for the account information. My answer is for the general question "Which account is Office using?", but if Ramhound posts an answer I'll yield to his.